# Codeception : Test Ajax/javascript requests

Tags: codeception

I'm new to codeception, and I need to write a functional test, which verifies if a certain page sends an ajax/javascript request, and also test if the request is executed as expected

Thank you

Raja

Comment: Since you won't send the request yourself then make sure you are waiting for the the page to be loaded and all ajax request completed then check the result in the page.

Comment: Hello Lauda, thank you for your reply, how can I check the result is page? for a specific request?

Comment: How would you test it manually?

Comment: Hello, it's a google analytics request, which is fired when the page is loaded, so manually I do that :1. Load the page, 2. check the ga code if it's present in my source code, 3. Go to network tab in my inspect console, and search for an url which contains the ga code.

Comment: With the first 2 points you should have no issue, open page, wait to load and check the ga code with a selector, regarding the last one I don't know if you really need to do it, if you have the ga code in a script then is executed and remains to check that all request are done using a wait with a script as the condition,Maybe a dev from your team can help with this.